# knockoutjs 1.3PRE "This template engine does not support anonymous templates nested within its templates"

Tags: knockout.js

I am having a problem with the new anonymous template engine. It cannot use nested templates. I get the error: "This template engine does not support anonymous templates nested within its templates".

My question: how do I force knockoutJS to use the jquery templates engine and not the new one. (until it also supports nested templates off course)

Thank you

Kindest regards
Jan

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A couple things that should help clear this up:

- If you reference jquery.tmpl.js before Knockout.js, then KO will set the jQueryTmplTemplateEngine as the default.
- The jQueryTmplTemplateEngine does not support anonymous templates.  This means that you can't use the control-flow bindings like `foreach`, `if`, `ifnot`, and `with` within it.  You can still use the template binding (including nested templates).
- You can control the default template engine by calling `ko.setTemplateEngine()`.  You would pass an instance of the engine that you want to use like `ko.setTemplateEngine(new ko.nativeTemplateEngine)`
- You can also pass the template engine to the template binding in the `templateEngine` parameter.

So, for your case, you would likely want to remove the reference to jquery.tmpl.js, so that the native template engine is being used by default.  The native template engine does support nested templates (anonymous or named).

Quick sample showing a named template with anonymous templates inside of it using the native template engine: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/GXFYB/

Comment: +1 - far better answer than mine! However, is it fair to say, that there are limitations / backward compatibility issues with the new knockout template engine. For instance, would your drag and drop sample (http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html) work with the new engine as it relies on passing parameters in the template data-bind?

Comment: Yes, there are some changes that would be necessary.  The drag and drop from the post uses `tmplItem` that is a jQuery templates concept, but can be replaced easily.  It also uses `templateOptions`, which is not current support in native templates.  I will look at creating an updated sample using the new syntax and see if I can find ways to clean it up further.

Comment: I will likely post this or add a note to the blog post, but here are a  the two samples in 1.3: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JEe2x/ and http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HzNuS/.  I cleaned them up a bit and wrapped the template binding to make it as simple as possible to add the binding.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try this first thing in the morning.

Comment: I tried it with the ko.setTemplateEngine(new ko.nativeTemplateEngine). It seems to work. Thank You again for the fast reply

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I removed the include to the tmpl js library but re-adding it fixed the problem. Are you sure you have included the jquery.tmpl.js library?

```
<script src='..<some path>../jquery.tmpl.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, I include the tmpl library first and the knockout library second. Maybe this is a factor?